# Save Random Image with PHP

Tags: php, image, curl, save

I need to save a random image from website to my computer. I know how to save images with PHP (I use curl), but I can't properly save random (dynamic) images.

Let's say that website (somesite.com) has some text content and IMG tag which looks like `<img src='somesite.com/image.php'>` and displays a random image. If I use browser, I can simply right-click and select "Save Image", so the image that I see on the screen will be saved (and they both will be the same).

However, if I use curl to open somesite.com (because I need to grab image description as well) and then use curl again to open somesite.com/image.php, images will be different (because a random one is selected every time user requests image.php).

Put simply, if somesite.com has text "this is rose", image.php will display a rose, and everything will look fine on browser. But if I use curl to open site, it may have text "this is tulip" and when I request image.php to save that image, another image will be displayed. How do I get exactly the same image saved that is displayed when first request is sent?

I guess it should be cached somewhere, or what?

Answer (score 0):

It's not cached anywhere you can most likely reach. The best way to do this would be to put the randomizing into the calling file, so something like `<img src='somesite.com/image.php?data=<?php echo $someRandomValue; ?>'>`. You'd then use this data parameter to generate the same image every time this image is requested with that same data parameter. Of course: if there are multiple variables that affect the image, you can add more parameters to the url or simply put them in an array and pass it along base64 encoded.

Comment: Yes, I can save such images (that use variables in URL) perfectly using PHP, but not all sites use variables in URL.

Comment: I misunderstood. If it's not your own site you're looking at and you're getting the random image using PHP from some other site, you will only feasibly be able to do this if you actually cache the image yourself. The easiest way to do this, I guess, would be to view the site through your own PHP script by getting the contents and echoing them after finding the `<img>` tags in it, downloading the pictures involved and caching them. You can then replace the <img> tags with their cached counterparts. Lastly, you'd need to store url to local filename conversions in a database or something.

Comment: Yes, I can echo the content, but how do I actually store (download) the image which is displayed? If I request that file, another random image is displayed then.

Comment: Download the image right away and store it. Then change all references of it in the HTML which you also downloaded to your local image instead of the dynamic one on the server. This way, the image you view will be the same one your server stores but yes, it does mean that your PHP script will have to serve as some sort of proxy.

Comment: Jeroen, how would I do that? Any simple example? I'm not very sure if I get the idea.

Comment: Comments really aren't the place for this but I'll try: `$text = file_get_contents("url");` `copy("image_url", "some/random/local/path");` `die(str_replace("image_url", "some/random/local/path", $text));` Your script would serve as a proxy, the image will be served from your server instead.